# Checking array identical or not is not working sometimes?

Tags: javascript

I tried to check two array is identical or not , but it's not working for array with length 1 case !

console output expected is

```
true
false
true
false
```

```js
var test1 = [0,1,2];
var test2 = [0,1,2];
console.log(test1.toString() == test2.toString());
console.log(test1.toString() == !test2.toString());

test1 = [0];
test2 = [0];
console.log(test1.toString() == test2.toString());
console.log(test1.toString() == !test2.toString());
```

Comment: Yeah That is why I want to know `why the last one is not getting false`

Comment: The second test should be `test1.toString() != test2.toString()`

Answer (score 5):

Cause the last one gets evaluated as:

```
 [0].toString() == ![0].toString()
 "0" == !"0"
 "0" == !true
 "0" == false
 0 == false
 false == false
 true
```

TLDR: Don't try to compare arrays by stringifying them, it will always result in some unexpected side effects.

Comment: while rightside !"0" became !true , leftside "0" became false

Answer (score 2):

To test if something is "not equal," you use `x != y` or `x !== y`, not `x == !y`:

```js
var test1 = [0,1,2];
var test2 = [0,1,2];
console.log(test1.toString() == test2.toString());
console.log(test1.toString() != test2.toString());

test1 = [0];
test2 = [0];
console.log(test1.toString() == test2.toString());
console.log(test1.toString() != test2.toString());

// third test to make sure we see that different arrays are different
test1 = [0];
test2 = [0, 1];
console.log(test1.toString() == test2.toString());
console.log(test1.toString() != test2.toString());

// another kind of different
test1 = [0];
test2 = [1];
console.log(test1.toString() == test2.toString());
console.log(test1.toString() != test2.toString());
```

**However**, converting arrays to strings to determine whether they're equivalent, while it will work with an array of numbers, won't work in the general case. You'll want to compare lengths and, if they're the same, perhaps use `every` to check the elements. Something like this:

```js
function arrayEqual(a, b) {
  return a.length === b.length &&
         a.every((v, i) => v == b[i]);
}

var test1 = [0,1,2];
var test2 = [0,1,2];
console.log(arrayEqual(test1, test2));
console.log(!arrayEqual(test1, test2));

test1 = [0];
test2 = [0];
console.log(arrayEqual(test1, test2));
console.log(!arrayEqual(test1, test2));

// third test to make sure we see that different arrays are different
test1 = [0];
test2 = [0, 1];
console.log(arrayEqual(test1, test2));
console.log(!arrayEqual(test1, test2));

// another kind of different
test1 = [0];
test2 = [1];
console.log(arrayEqual(test1, test2));
console.log(!arrayEqual(test1, test2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to use strict comparison  (`===` and `!==`) for this to work and skip the use of the `!` boolean negation operator that will coerses the string into a boolean value. You can take a look to [coercion](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-js-coercion-ff5684475bfc) for more info.

```js
var test1 = [0,1,2];
var test2 = [0,1,2];
console.log(test1.toString() === test2.toString());
console.log(test1.toString() !== test2.toString());

test1 = [0];
test2 = [0];
console.log(test1.toString() === test2.toString());
console.log(test1.toString() !== test2.toString());
```

However, that approach won't work on all the cases, example:

```js
var test1 = [""];
var test2 = [null];
console.log(test1.toString() === test2.toString());
console.log(test1.toString() !== test2.toString());
```

And it will be better to use something like this, that uses the [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method:

```js
var test1 = [""];
var test2 = [null];
var test3 = [1,2,3,4];
var test4 = [1,2,3,4];

const compareArray = (a1, a2) =>
{
    return a1.length === a2.length && a1.every((val, idx) => val === a2[idx]);
}

console.log(compareArray(test1, test2));
console.log(compareArray(test3, test4));
```

Comment: `==` vs. `===` is not the issue. The issue is applying `!` to a string and comparing the resulting boolean to another string. Your change would make the second test case false even if the arrays were different.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this method?

```
var test1 = [0,1,2];
var test2 = [0,1,2];
console.log(test1.every((item, i) => test2[i] === item));
console.log(!test1.every((item, i) => test2[i] === item));

test1 = [0];
test2 = [0];
console.log(test1.every((item, i) => test2[i] === item));
console.log(!test1.every((item, i) => test2[i] === item));
```

I sure it will work.
Hope this helps, have a nice day.